# PHP MYSQL PDO. When I do a SELECT, it doesn't return all table fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I try to execute my SUCCESSFUL Select in mysql database, it returns all my fields except the first one. (yeah, it sount very srange).

And if the select only returns 1 field, it won't print any value.
If the select returns 2 values, only 1 will be printed (the 2nd one). 
etc.

I don't understand why is it happening!

```php
    $vector=array();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products";
    $con=new DataBase();
    $resultado=$con->selectQuery($sql,$vector); //you have this funtion below

    if($resultado!=null){
        if (!$resultado->fetchColumn()){
            //no hay productos
            $cadena="No products in our web";
        }
        else{
            $cadena=$resultado; //IF ALL HAVE GONE CORRECT
        }
    }
    else{
        $cadena="Sorry, we are having some problems. Try again later.";
    }

  if (is_string($cadena))
  {
       //some code.
  }
  else
  {
       ///////////////////////
       // HERE I PROCEED TO TAKE THE DATA OF THE SELECT.
        foreach ($cadena as $row)   
        {
           $prods .="$row[price]";
        }
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  //selectQuery FUNCTION...

  public function selectQuery($sql,$vector){
    //select
    if($this->connect()){//data to connect to the DB. It works well.
        $sentencia = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sentencia->execute($vector);
        $this->disconnect();
    }else{
        $sentencia=null;
    }

    //$jjj=$sentencia->fetchAll(); //s'ha de fer si no a vegades dona error
    //print_r($jjj) ; exit;
    return $sentencia;

}
```

Comment: you should do `fetchAll()` directly after execute and return the resulting array instead of the statement instance.

Comment: I tried to  do: $arrayReturned=$sentencia->fetchAll(); return $arrayReturned. But the problem persists. 
Should I change something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check documentation fetchColumn() - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

You fetching only one column instead of all of them. Use fetchAll() function to select all columns fetchAll() - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php